# Three lines of code look the same and only one works. Why?

Tags: gwt

I have some GWT code here. I am trying to change the background color of a widget:

```
this.getElement().setAttribute("backgroundColor", backgroundColor);
this.getElement().setPropertyString("backgroundColor", backgroundColor);
this.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("backgroundColor", backgroundColor);
```

Usually in code I can tell by the name of the function what the code does... but in this case all three lines of code looks the same and "read the same"! (Reading the javadoc did not help either.I went to the javadoc because that usually helps me understand what code does. The javadoc did not help.)

My question to you is: **Please explain what is the differences between these three lines of code (for instance why do you need to call getStyle())? Why does the last line work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the difference between

```
<tag backgroundColor="#f0f0f0">
```

and

```
<tag style="background-color:#f0f0f0">
```

Answer (score 4):

```
this.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("backgroundColor", backgroundColor);
```

is the only line that access the actual `style` information, `properties` and `attributes` manipulate the element directly and don't have anything to do with the `Style` that is associated with an element.

And just as an addition, you should really be using a style sheet and changing the style instead of setting `inline` this way.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of an educated guess...

Line 1 you are accessing the element's attributes not the styling attributes.

Line 2 would access properties on the element not the styling.

Line 3 actually gets the styling properties and then changes them accordingly.